# What does “mensa” mean?

Tags: meaning

From Eric Temple Bell’s *Men of Mathematics*:

> All this [definition of “function” and substituting numbers for variables] is familiar to anyone whose grammar-school education ended
>   not more than thirty or forty years ago, but some may have forgotten
>   what they did in arithmetic as children, just as others could not
>   decline the Latin ***mensa*** to save their souls.

[***Mensa*** from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensa_International):

> Mensa, meaning table, can refer to the following:
>
> - Mensa International is an organization for persons with high IQs.
> - Mensa is a southern constellation.
> - Mensa is a term used by geologists to refer to an extraterrestrial mesa.
> - Mensa (restaurant) is a type of restaurant that specialises in cheap food for students.

I’m not sure whether any of these four meanings can fit the context. Maybe *mensa* was some kind of restaurant or school textbook?

I think the [third meaning below may make sense](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mensa):

1. A table.
2. A table of food; meal, course, feast.
3. A sacrificial table, altar.
4. vocative singular of mēnsa

Comment: It's General Reference. From the [Wikipedia page for Mensa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mensa_International) *- **mensa** means "table" in Latin, as is symbolized in the organization's logo, and was chosen to demonstrate the round-table nature of the organization; the coming together of equals.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm not so sure that this definition "saves souls"

Comment: Zeta, "Latin mensa" is/was a mensa where Jesus was/is present, and I think @Andrew, who is an expert of Christianity, can confirm.

Comment: @ Zeta: I don't understand that comment about saving souls, but if you don't like Wikipedia's definition, you can always consider the answer to [the second question in the FAQ on Mensa's own site](http://www.mensa.org.uk/about-mensa/faqs#n84) - *It is not an acronym - it is Latin for ‘table’.  It denotes a round table where all members are equal.*

Comment: So, "others could not decline the **Latin mensa** to save their souls" is a wordplay in which "decline the Latin mensa" makes the pair with "save their souls".

Comment: And so, answers below are all wrong!

Comment: @Carlo_R. Can you explain more (or perhaps post an answer)?

Comment: @Carlo_R. I don't think you're right: you're reading far too much into it. The plain reading is the one to go for.

Comment: Zeta, sorry, if @Andrew says I'm wronging here there is no need of further explanations. Thank for your your feedback.

Comment: You should really be asking "What does ***decline*** mean? Did you presume *decline* = 'politely refuse' here, as is much more likely? Rather, see *decline*: 4 [*with object*]  (in the grammar of Latin, Greek, and certain other languages) state the forms of (a noun, pronoun, or adjective) corresponding to cases, number, and gender. (http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/decline?q=decline+)

Comment: The declension of _mensa_ is traditionally the very first thing a Latin beginner would be taught. Bell is using it in that sense. It means table but that's irrelevant - it was the canonical example of a first declension noun.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reference "could not decline the Latin *mensa* to save their souls"  is a reference to **doing something which should be extremely easy.** *Mensa* is a perfectly regular first-declension feminine noun, and declines in a set way:

| Case | Major Use | Latin Example | English Equivalent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Nominative | Subject | *mensa* | *table* |
| Accusative | Direct Object | *mensam* | *table* |
| Genitive | Possessive | *mensae* | *of the table* |
| Dative | Indirect Object | *mensae* | *to/for the table* |
| Ablative | Means or Manner | *mensa* | *by/with the table* |
| Vocative | Direct address | *mensa* | *O table!* |

However, there were some who could not do this even if their very lives depended on it.

Comment: ... mensae, mensas, mensarum, mensis, mensis, mensae

Comment: Paradigms parsed for [Latin nouns](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinNouns.pdf) (_mensa_ is a noun) and [Latin verbs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/LatinVerbs.pdf).

Comment: And here's [what happened to those paradigms](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TheGrammaticalizationCycle.pdf) while the Roman speakers were becoming Romance Speakers.

Answer (score 7):

I think the meaning of *mensa* is not relevant here.  In Latin, one can *decline* a noun, by giving all its forms, one after the other.  Bell is saying that even those who learned to do that back in school, may no longer remember it.

Answer (score 4):

"*mensa*" here is not English. It is literally the Latin word *mensa*, which happens to translate to "table", but the English translation is not relevant.

Rather, the word is used here as an example of a very simple Latin word that an adult -- whose learning as a schoolchild is forgotten -- might be totally unable to decline (in the grammatical sense of "to inflect"), even if the salvation of his soul depended on making such a declension.

Comment: Yes you're right but the point is that _mensa_ was the canonical example of a first declension noun that a Latin beginner would memorise. It's the very first thing they would learn.